# Allow MongoDB Read/Write But Disallow Delete Permission

Tags: mongodb, permissions

I want a user to be able to read and update, but not able to delete in any collection for MongoDB.

The command I used is:

```
db.createUser(
  {
   user: "user",
    pwd: "user",
    privileges: [
       { resource: { db: "icif_pattern" , collection: "" },
         actions: [ "find", "createCollection", "dbStats", "collStats" ] },

    ],
    roles: []
  }
)
```

But it throws an error:

> ```
> Error: couldn't add user: "privileges" is not a valid argument to
> createUser
> ```

I am following the information found in the following article:

[Mongo user roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/system-roles-collection/) (MongoDB Docs)

Answer (score 2):

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/collection-level-access-control/%20) Collection-level access control allows administrators to grant users privileges that are scoped to specific collections.

Administrators can implement `collection-level` access control through user-defined roles. By creating a role with privileges that are scoped to a specific collection in a particular database, administrators can provision users with roles that grant privileges on a collection level.

**Required Access**

To create a role in a database, you must have:

- the createRole action on that database resource.
- the grantRole action on that database to specify privileges for the
  new role as well as to specify roles to inherit from.

`Built-in` roles `userAdmin` and `userAdminAnyDatabase` provide `createRole` and `grantRole` actions on their respective resources.

To create a role with `authenticationRestrictions` specified, you must have the `setAuthenticationRestriction` action on the database resource which the role is created.

```
use admin
db.createRole(
   {
     role: "myClusterwideAdmin",
     privileges: [
       { resource: { cluster: true }, actions: [ "addShard" ] },
       { resource: { db: "config", collection: "" }, actions: [ "find", "update", "insert", "remove" ] },
       { resource: { db: "users", collection: "usersCollection" }, actions: [ "update", "insert", "remove" ] },
       { resource: { db: "", collection: "" }, actions: [ "find" ] }
     ],
     roles: [
       { role: "readWrite", db: "admin" }
     ]
   },
   { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 }
)
```

**Roles**

In the roles field, you can specify both built-in roles and user-defined roles.

```
{ role: "<role>", db: "<database>" }
```

For your further ref [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createRole/#db.createRole) , [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-user-defined-roles/#user-defined-roles)